# preg_match() or similar function for checking currency

Tags: php, regex, syntax, preg-match

```
1.449,00
1.000.000,55
19,90
etc
etc
```

I know what I listed above are very variable but there are possibilities for currency. I'm looking for a `preg_match()` example or any other function to deal with possible cases above. I tried with example below but it is not working properly. Any chance given me a most appropriate pattern for it?

```
if (! preg_match('/^[0-9.,]$/', $currency)) { echo 'No good.'; }
```

Comment: You should look at [`NumberFormatter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
/^((?:\d{1,3}[,\.]?)+\d*)$/
```

This matches:

```
^         - Start of string
(         - Capture the following:
 (?:      
  \d{1,3} - One to three digits
  [,\.]?  - And an optional separator (comma or period)
 )+       - One or more times
 \d*      - Zero or more digits
)
$         - End of string
```

It works by iteratively matching everything to the left side of the separator (if it's present), and then has `\d*` to pick up any optional fractions of currency.

You can see it passes [all of your tests](http://regexr.com?31ovb).

**Edit:** An updated regex looks like this:

```
^((?:\d\.\d{3}\.|\d{1,3}\.)?\d{1,3},\d{1,2})$
```

Where we match either:

- `\d\.\d{3}\.` - One digit, a period, three digits, a period, OR
- `\d{1,3}\.` - One and three digits, a period
- None of the above (because of the `?`)

Then, we match:

- `\d{1,3},` - One to three digits and a comma, followed by
- `\d{1,2}`  - One or two digits

Comment: I think I modified syntax after your answer to reduce possibilities so only `2 or 1 digit comes after comma` and `max 7 digits before comma and separated with dots only`. Link above giving me "server error". Sorry for being pain but could we modify your code for this reduced pattern? Thanks

Comment: @MadMax - I've updated my answer, it should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Add `+` after the `]` to allow more than just one character.