# preg_match function for checking currency Value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have some values like

```
£523.22
9454
££45523
741.03
etc
```

I want to remove this £ from the value and check that whether it is valid vaue or not So that I can insert them into database
I Create following expression with the help of [preg_match() or similar function for checking currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850022/preg-match-or-similar-function-for-checking-currency) .y

```
$job_order=(preg_match("/^[£]*[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)?$/",$value) ? str_replace("£","",$value) : '' );
```

if $value =£523.22 then its return null . But if its  741.03 thn its working .I don't know whats wrong with  this preg_match .
I m importing this value from .Mer(Merge) file.If I simply write $value=£523.22 then its working But When its reads value from the file then its not identifying pound sign

Comment: You can remove pound mark and check if the rest is a number. `is_numeric()`

Comment: yes I tried than if I removed pound mark then its working

Comment: What are your criterae for the number format (thousand separators, number of decimals, leading decimal point, max and min values)? Can the currency symbol be at the end? Is it always a `£`?

Comment: There is not criteria for that. Here just want to remove pound symbol and check that its valid or not

Comment: And if the user enter something like this: `12£34`?

Comment: Thats never happen. If it is thn it should be count as 1234.Just want to removed £.

Comment: Are thousand separators allowed or not?

Comment: There is already validation added for that.

Comment: So there are no thousand separators.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte :Yes ,there are no thousand separators

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$job_order = strtr($value, '£', '');
if (is_numeric($job_order)) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$value = preg_replace(/'£(?=\d+)/' , '', $value);
```

or, if value can be `£.50`

```
$value = preg_replace(/'£(?=\.?\d+)/' , '', $value);
```

Comment: its not remove the pound symbol I means  regular exp is not match with the value

Comment: @Kreya: Sorry, I don't get you. May be you want to modify your question and add some sample strings and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try this for currency match `/^((?:\d{1,3}[,\.]?)+\d*)$/`

```
(preg_match('/^((?:\d{1,3}[,\.]?)+\d*)$/',,$value) ? str_replace("£","",$value) : '' );
```

`\d{1,3}` One to three digits

you can increase number using `\d{1,X}`

Comment: Thanks for reply .Here its not eliminate pound symbol. for £523.22 its giving null value instead of 523.22

Comment: you can debug the code line by line i think my ans it's work for you..you can change this line of code instead of this  str_replace("£"," ",$value)

Comment: visit the following link it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982291/how-to-check-if-an-entered-value-is-currency